# At least two girls sit together probability

Tags: probability

> Three girls $G_1,G_2,G_3$ and three boys $B_1,B_2,B_3$ are made to sit in a row randomly. The probability that at least two girls are together is ....

My try: Probability of no girl together: _B_B_B_ here in dashed places girls be seated so probability is $\dfrac{4*3*2*3*2}{6!}=\dfrac15$ and hence probability of at least two girls are together is $1-\frac15=\frac45$. Am I correct? I am asking this because I have options: $0, 1/10, 1/20, 9/10$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right and none of the options is correct.

Comment: @RohitGupta, thanks man! I was nervous for a while.

Comment: Your solution is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 4/5. The probability of no girls together given arrangement GBGBGB is 3! for the girl choices and 3! for the boy choices. Thus there is $3!\cdot 3!$ for this arrangement. Moreover there is also arrangement BGBGBG which is likewise the same. 
Another arrangement is 
GBBGBG or
GBGBBG
of which then is similarly the same probability.
Altogether, there is $1-\frac{4(3! \cdot 3!)}{6!} = 4/5$ chances for atleast two girls together.

Comment: Wouldn't there also be a possibility like GBBGBG?

Comment: @RohitGupta You're right. I edited it.